# Static routes and multiple routers

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, ubiquiti, accounting

I have the following set up:

```
Ubiquiti USG router (WAN: DHCP client: 192.168.20.100/24 GW: 192.168.20.1)
Ubiquiti USG router (LAN: DHCP server: 192.168.1.1/24)
|
Cisco 3750 Switch Port on VLAN 1 (LAN: DHCP client: 192.168.1.100/24 GW: 192.168.1.1)
Cisco 3750 Switch Port on VLAN 2 (LAN: DHCP server: 172.27.71.1/24)
|
PC (LAN: DHCP client: 172.27.71.100/24 GW: 172.27.71.1)

Cisco 3750 Switch Port on VLAN 3 (LAN: DHCP server: 172.27.72.1/24)
|
Server (LAN: DHCP client: 172.27.72.100/24 GW: 172.27.72.1)
```

Now in order to get it working I configured IP routing and DHCP on the 3750. This allow the PC and server to communicate via the Cisco switch as it is their common gateway.

In order to get internet access to the Server, I added a static routes:

In the Ubiquiti USG:
    172.27.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.100

But this didn't work! In order to get it to work I had to add another static route to the upstream router:

```
172.27.0.0/16 via 192.168.20.100
```

Now we are getting to the questions:

1. If the Ubiquiti USG is NATing the outbound traffic, then why do I need to add a static route to the upstream router that includes the 172.27.2.0/24 subnet, isn't this out of context?
2. The Ubiquiti USG performs bandwidth accounting, but it doesn't list the server or the phone in its client list, it only lists the Cisco switch. If the Cisco switch does not perform NAT then why is the traffic being attributed to the switch?
3. What do I need to change in my setup to make the USG aware of the devices connected to the Cisco switch - while still allowing inter-Vlan communication to occur on the Cisco switch?

I know I could get it to work by defining all the VLANs on the USG and running a DHCP server for each and just running a trunk to the Cisco switch (i.e. router on a stick) but then all the inter-VLAN traffic between the vlans would have to go via the USG and that is significantly slower.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: But the question is about a Ubiquiti USG enterprise router and a cisco 3750 switch aren't these enterprise?

Comment: It is still home networking. See the [help/on-topic]: "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about professionally managed networks in a business environment._" and "_(Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.)"_ and in the off-topic section: "_residential/home networking_". You should always check which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed, before asking on an SE site.

Comment: I actually have enterprise-grade equipment in my home, but any questions I may have about my home network would be off-topic here.

Comment: So because my business is operating out of my home it is regarded as home networking?

Comment: This was a community decision. If you have enough reputation, you can question this in [meta] where such topics are discussed, and you may be able to get a consensus to change the community.

Comment: I have just reread the rules regarding off topic and I disagree with your interpretation of my post. I'm asking a question about setting up a business network using equipment typically used by professionals. How is that off topic?

Comment: You can disagree, but the place to disagree is in [meta].

Comment: Why would you think that your friends router and your router don't both need static routes to a network to which is neither directly connected nor told to each by a routing protocol?

Comment: Can you just answer one more thing? Given my reworded question, do you still think it off topic? And if so, can you please relate that directly to http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic because to my understanding this is a "professionally managed networks in a business environment."

Comment: The problem you seem to not be able to wrap your head around is the configuration of his home router. and that is off-topic here. There is a reason we don't allow questions about consumer-grade equipment here. Those devices don't always work as you may expect. At the very least, you need to provide all the equipment models and configurations to see where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: Since you wouldn't fix the question to meet the site rules, I took the liberty of editing your question to conform to the rules for Network Engineering. If you disagree, you should roll it back.

Comment: "business network" is debatable -- I won't, however. "professionally managed" it is clearly not. Your base question is one of the most basic concepts of networking: *routing*. You've added a subnet for which the rest of the network is *unaware*.

Comment: @RickyBeam, If you read the original question, pre-edits, you will see that this "business" network is a residential network to a friend's house to which this network, in another house, is attached, via a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: @RonMaupin It is a business network. It just happens to get its internet from a friend of mine. And yes that internet comes via a wifi connection but it is a p2p link using 500mm dish antenna. So yes it is enterprise equipment.

Comment: And, as @RickyBeam pointed out, it is not a professionally managed network, and, by consensus, it is off-topic because it is behind a residential broadband gateway: http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234/8499

Comment: @RonMaupin Stop arguing semantics and grow up. I am a professional and I manage the network - do you have another definition for a professionally managed network?

Comment: Are you claiming to be a network engineer? Apparently, you don't quite grasp routing. Routers need to know where to send traffic, either through static routes, or from a routing protocol. The tour for the site tells you, "_Network Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for network engineers._

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes I am a network engineer. I understand routing. I understand why I need a static route in my USG. My question was why do I need a static route if the router is NATing the traffic? I know that it should not be required - but I was looking for some confirmation. I posed it as a question as I didn't want to lead people to the answer I had drawn. I have now confirmed there is a bug in the USG that means not all outbound traffic is NATed, hence the need for the extra static route.

Comment: You insisted on getting an answer for why your friend's residential router needed a static route, and that is clearly off-topic here, as are any questions about anything behind it. I don't understand why you don't respect the community's decision. I did answer your question from a perspective of not including the residential router. I also answered your next question, which also makes me skeptical of the network engineer claim. You got answers to the questions from the perspective of what may be on-topic here. I don't think anyone here would touch the residential router, and nobody has.

Comment: You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: configurations of your devices, routing tables from your devices, etc.

Comment: My question is not off-topic. I have read the rules. I have posted in the meta forum, no one replied - except you. You are the only person who is claiming it is off topic. What you need to come to terms with is the rules are worded around the how the network is used, how the network is managed and what kind of equipment is used. They do not focus on where the network is located. If I had used the word "farm" instead of "house" in my OP would you have complained? Also the OP was not about my friends router, it was about the USG. my friends router was just the device highlighting the problem.

Comment: I think that it is obvious from the fact that I was the only one who tried to help you that a question for anything behind a residential router is off-topic. That was decided a long time ago in this answer to the [meta] question: http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/234/8499

Comment: @RonMaupin  I have now found out the brand of my friends router, it is a Mikrotik RB2011UiAS-IN does that meet your threshold for enterprise?

Comment: It is a residential network router. Why does the model matter? I have a high-end Cisco enterprise router as my residential router, along with enterprise gear. Any questions I have about my home/business network are off-topic here, as is your question. You keep wanting to play word games to make a residential network fit this site.

Comment: oh well thats pretty simple "A "home" is when the broadband provider classifies it as residential.", Well that is not the case I'm in my friend is on a symmetrical business plan.

Comment: @RonMaupin Isn't it obvious! I thought your objection was to the hardware not meeting the enterprise threshold as that is actually mentioned in the rules http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic How was I suppose to know you were talking about the grade of internet connection, it doesn't say anything about that in the rules. If it had I known that was what you were on about I could have cleared this up ages ago.

Comment: I only mentioned that [meta] answer three different times to you, and the [help/on-topic] says under Off-Topic, "_residential/home networking_." And, your original question said it was a home network: "_I get my internet from my friends house:_" You keep sliding around what it is, trying to meet what is on-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Do you own your own business?

Comment: I work at home for a large enterprise; it's in my user information. You got three answers to your other question, but I was the only one that bothered to try to answer this question.

Comment: @RonMaupin I appreciate what you are doing here. But you need to appreciate that I read the rules before I posted and "residential/home networking." is vague. I assumed that was referring to whether it use was residential. If the community wants to exclude any question about residential grade internet connections that's fine - but update the rules. There are lots of cheap stakes businesses using residential connections, I'm not one of them my friend is on a proper symmetric fibre connection.

Comment: This does not sound "professionally managed" I am not trying to be demaning...but running static routes in enterprise environments is horrible for many reasons namely the first one that comes to mind being there is no redundancy if a route goes down......not to mention the high administrative cost of managing an environment like this. Look up floating static route and think about that in addition to a valid routing protocol, that would be my advice.

Answer (score 1):

To answer questions two and three (question one is for a home networking, consumer-grade device), DHCP for VLAN 2 is done on the switch, rather than the router, so the router doesn't know about them, either through DHCP or via layer-2. You could run DHCP for both VLANs on the router, then the router will know about devices on both VLANs, or you could run both VLANs on the router so that it can see all the devices via layer-2.

> I know I could get it to work by defining all the VLANs on the USG and
>   running a DHCP server for each and just running a trunk to the Cisco
>   switch (i.e. router on a stick) but then all the inter-VLAN traffic
>   between the vlans would have to go via the USG and that is
>   significantly slower.

Why do you think that? it is probably slower by tens of microseconds, and you will probably be unable to see any difference or measure it.

**Edit (based on the edited question):**

Your router doesn't know how to get to the route defined on the switch unless you specifically configure it, or you run a routing protocol between the router and the switch. Your route doesn't know where to send the traffic destined for the `172.27.2.0/24` network, except to drop it or send it to a default route.

The the need for the static route on your friend's home-network, consumer-grade router is off-topic here.

Comment: Why do I think it is slower? Because I can connect my file server to the switch with 4x 1Gbps in an LACP trunk and then I can have 4 workstations pulling 1Gbps each off the server. If I have to route all that through a single 1Gbps link to the router then I'm limiting my throughput to 1Gbps and effectively going to half duplex.

Comment: As I wrote, you can put both VLANs on the switch. It is a very non-standard design to have one on the router, and one on the switch. Depending on the channeling algorithm you use, and the addresses/ports assigned to the hosts, you may not get the full bandwidth you think you get. It is possible that two hosts are assigned to each of two of the channeled links, or even all four on one of the links.

Comment: OK I have expressed my question more fully here: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30406/cisco-3750-configuration-for-static-routes-per-vlan

Answer (score 1):

> If the Ubiquiti USG is NATing the outbound traffic, then why do I need
>   to add a static route to the upstream router that includes the
>   172.27.2.0/24 subnet, isn't this out of context?

I think you're 100% correct, and that the problem is not on the upstream router but on the USG. There is a big "If" at the start of your question; it sounds like the USG is not really doing NAT. Personally I don't know this specific product but it seems extremely likely that just adding a static route is not enough, i.e. it is not by default doing NAT for anything arriving on its "inside" interface, probably only for the directly connected subnet. So you will have to somehow tell it to do NAT for 172.27.0.0/16 as well.